# localstorage more than 1 button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i need to make 2 (or more) buttons that will save after i close the browser so that if i open it 
i will have 2 white buttons instead of 2 blue buttons.
So how do i manage to save every button without needing to make different functions for every button?

```
<script>

function save() {
var storeButton = document.getElementById("testButton1");;
localStorage.setItem("buttonColor", storeButton.style.backgroundColor);

}

function load() {
    var color = localStorage.getItem("buttonColor");
    if (color) {
    document.getElementById("testButton1").style.backgroundColor = color;

  }
}
</script>

<body onload="load()">

<input type="button" id="testButton" value="Save" onclick="save()"/>
<input class="blue" type="button" id="testButton1" value="click me to turn white" style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">
<input class="blue" type="button" id="testButton2" value="click me to turn white" style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">


</body>
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a generic function for this task, use a class name in the button to get all their references from the DOM and iterate over them, something as follows:

```
<script>

function save() {
    var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName("save-button-style");
    var button;

    for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
        button = buttonList[i];
        localStorage.setItem(button.id, button.style.backgroundColor);
    }
}

function load() {
    var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName("save-button-style");
    var button;

    for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
        button = buttonList[i];
        var color = localStorage.getItem(button.id);
        if (color) {
            button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<body onload="load()">

<input type="button" id="testButton" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
<input class="blue save-button-style" type="button" id="testButton1" value="click me to turn white" style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">
<input class="blue save-button-style" type="button" id="testButton2" value="click me to turn white" style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there're only two buttons something like this should work:

```
function save() {
    var storeButton = document.getElementById("testButton1");;
    localStorage.setItem("buttonColor1", storeButton.style.backgroundColor);

    storeButton = document.getElementById("testButton2");;
    localStorage.setItem("buttonColor2", storeButton.style.backgroundColor);
}

function load() {
    var color = localStorage.getItem("buttonColor1");
    if (color) {
        document.getElementById("testButton1").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    color = localStorage.getItem("buttonColor2");
    if (color) {
        document.getElementById("testButton2").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: need to do more so i can add buttons